# linq to xml enumerating over descendants

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

Hi trying to write a simple linq query from a tutorial I read. But i cannot seem to get it to work. I am trying to display both the address in the attached xml document, but can only display the first one. Can someone help me figure out why both aren't being printed. Thank you very much

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Emails>
  <Email group="FooBar">
    <Subject>Test subject</Subject>
    <Content>Test Content</Content>
    <EmailTo>
      <Address>foo@bar.com</Address>
      <Address>bar@foo.com</Address>
    </EmailTo>
  </Email>
</Emails> 




    Dim steve = (From email In emailList.Descendants("Email") _
                Where (email.Attribute("group").Value.Equals("FooBar")) _
                Select content = email.Element("EmailTo").Descendants("Address")).ToList()



    If Not steve Is Nothing Then
        For Each addr In steve
            Console.WriteLine(addr.Value)
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current query returns a `List<IEnumerable<XElement>>`. That means you need two nested `foreach` loops: one to loop over the list, and another to loop over the content of the `IEnumerable<XElement>`.

Instead, you could update your LINQ query to use the [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) method and get to the addresses directly. In query format a `SelectMany` is represented by using a second `from` clause to indicate a subquery. This would resemble the following:

```
Dim query = (From email In emailList.Descendants("Email") _
            Where (email.Attribute("group").Value.Equals("FooBar")) _
            From addr In email.Element("EmailTo").Descendants("Address") _
            Select addr.Value).ToList()

If query.Any() Then
    For Each addr In query
        Console.WriteLine(addr)
    Next
End If
```

Also, the `ToList` isn't needed if you only want to iterate over the results and don't intend to use the result as a list for other purposes.

**EDIT:** to explain how this query works let's break it down in 2 parts:

First:

```
From email In emailList.Descendants("Email") _
Where (email.Attribute("group").Value.Equals("FooBar")) _
```

This queries for all `<Email>` nodes and only matches the ones that have a *group* attribute value of "FooBar".

Second:

```
From addr In email.Element("EmailTo").Descendants("Address") _
Select addr.Value
```

This is a subquery that continues where the first part (above) ended. It essentially is a way to further query the results of the original query. Here we query for all `<Address>` nodes and, finally, select their `Value` for the inner text of the nodes. The reason we need to do this is because `Descendants("Address")` returns a `IEnumerable<XElement>` containing all "Address" elements. We need to perform an additional query (or `foreach`) to iterate over those values and extract their values.

Another way to illustrate this is by breaking it down in 2 queries:

```
Dim query1 = From email In emailList.Descendants("Email") _
             Where (email.Attribute("group").Value.Equals("FooBar"))
             Select email.Element("EmailTo").Descendants("Address")
Dim query2 = query1.SelectMany(Function(addr) addr.Select(Function(a) a.Value))
```

Notice the use of `SelectMany` in `query2`. The `Select` in `query2` is that additional effort to loop over the `IEnumerable` that I mentioned earlier. The original query is clearer than query1/query2, but I wrote them just to clarify the point.

Comment: I dont fully understand how your linq statement works. Can you break it down for me or point me to some resources i can read. What I am not understanding is the second from clause. How does that give me what i need. Thanks for the answer and help

Comment: Sorry, just looked at the return results and the results I am expecting are
Foo@bar.com NEWLINE
bar@Foo.com

what i am getting is
foo@bar.com NEWLINE
foo@bar.com

Comment: whoops, my mistake i didnt include your select statement sorry. Answer works as advertised, can you explain to me why it works though. Thank you

Comment: @gh9 added an explanation to my post. Hope that helps!

Comment: Ahmad, the nested From respectively SelectMany is fine but I wonder why you put the `If query.Any() Then` around the `For Each`, the `For Each` alone suffices to enumerate the query results and the `query.Any()` check is not needed nor does it achieve anything.

Comment: @Martin you're right about `Any` being redundant. I included it to replace the OP's original check against `Nothing` in case the OP planned to do something else if no results were found. Otherwise I agree that it can be removed.